# Negative Price for Custom Option

Tags: magento-1.8

Is it feasible to use negative values for prices if you want the option to reduce the base price of the product while adding Custom Options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, custom option prices can be negative.

Comment: Do you see any way for this to go below 0.00$? E.g. Base Price 5.00$ and we want to enable options that will result in -3.00$ but applying 8*-1.00$ will result in position total of 0.00$ with no option to toggle this behaviour.

Comment: A negative final price for a product is hardly possible. If you search for `max(0,` in the core code, you will find that the price is capped at 0 in all price models, but also during tax calculation. Allowing products with negative prices woule need lots of rewrites.

Answer (score 3):

You could go with a configurable product which has the ability to subtract from the base price.

Otherwise, lower the base price and give two options. One which adds up to the given price and one that doesn't